# Get a list of array of lists idexes with greates elementrs counts C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array of lists:

```
private List<int>[] Graph = new List<int>[n];
```

For example:

```
Graph[0] = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
Graph[1] = new List<int>() { 0 };
Graph[2] = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 3, 4 };
Graph[3] = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 1 };
Graph[4] = new List<int>() { 2, 3 };

Graph[0].Count // give 2
Graph[1].Count // give 1
Graph[2].Count // give 4
Graph[3].Count // give 3
Graph[4].Count // give 2
```

And I want to get an array (or list) which includes the indexes of the lists sorted by the count of the elements in each list. So for this example it will be:

```
orderList[0] -> 2 //(because Graph[2].Count give 4)

orderList[1] -> 3 //(because Graph[3].Count give 3)

orderList[2] -> 0 //(because Graph[0].Count give = 2)

orderList[3] -> 4 //(because Graph[4].Count give = 2)

orderList[4] -> 1 //(because Graph[1].Count give = 1)
```

orderList is an n-elements array.

Comment: Do you want to sort the list? Highest to lowest?

Comment: As evident by his example data he wants an array of the indexes of the lists in the original array sorted by the number of elements in each list.

Comment: We made a mess of this question. I approved a suggested edit that changes the meaning of the question and I can't reject it now.

Comment: Wait, give me a second, it's not easy to explain for me, especially, that I have almost 40 Celsius deg fever now.

Comment: Do you want an array or indexes (i.e. orderList is int[]) or you want an array of Lists (i.e. orderList is List<int>[]) or something else?

Comment: @user1825271 `it's not easy to explain for me, especially, that I have almost 40 Celsius deg fever now.` then what you need is not code or a set of instructions. You need a doctor. That's a **very** dangerous temperature. And  I believe stilgar already answered your question.

Comment: @JoshPart thank You fof caring, I really appreciate it, but to be honest I'm more worried that I present my problem so incomprehensibly, that many person do not understand it. It is shame for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the select method that incorporates an index to combine the list count with the index

```
int[] orderList = Graph.Select((list, index) => new { Count = list.Count, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Count).Select(a => a.Index).ToArray();
```

More readable query syntax

```
int[] orderList = (from pair in Graph.Select((list, index) => new { Count = list.Count, Index = index })
                   orderby pair.Count descending
                   select pair.Index).ToArray();
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, someone is trying to draw more attention to their answer more than likely by down voting.  I added the same comment to my answer, because someone down voted.

Comment: Yeah I know you didn't I ask whoever did. BTW I do believe that all other answers here misunderstood the question but I still didn't go on a downvote streak.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the upvoted answer is wrong.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
Graph = Graph.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToArray();
```

Comment: No, he does not want a new array of lists he wants an array of indexes

Answer (score -2):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<int>[] orderedGraph = graph.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToArray();
```

This will order array descending using list "count" property.

Remember to add using:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: He asks for an array of int not for an array of list of int.

Comment: Read carefully - he want array of lists. He wrote it: "array which includes all lists lists elements in a descending order based". So I do not understand my -1.

Comment: No, that's a bad edit. His original text is "and i want to get array which include order of greatest count of lists elements." Notice that the data is clearly integers.

Comment: I think we can not assume anything until author marks answer. :) IMHO non of this is clear enough.

Comment: The question sucks because of OP's bad English but the example data is pretty clear in my opinion.

Comment: Ech I know, that my English is bad, to be honest, it was the most difficult thing I wanted to express in English ever. First, I thought 15 minutes how to define this problem in my native language, and then I tried to translate. For now I do not know if the problem is clearly presented. I will be grateful if someone would write if it is clearly now.

Comment: In current version it is clear. Previous made little mess with answers. :)